Vulkan Image Layout Transition
I have two subpasses, first one does offScreen rendering and second one does onScreen rendering and uses first subpass as a input attachment. This is the code
VkAttachmentDescription attachmentDescriptions[2]{};
attachmentDescriptions[0].format = swapchainObject.swapchainFormat;
attachmentDescriptions[0].samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
attachmentDescriptions[0].loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_LOAD;
attachmentDescriptions[0].storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
attachmentDescriptions[0].stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
attachmentDescriptions[0].stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
attachmentDescriptions[0].initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;
attachmentDescriptions[0].finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;

attachmentDescriptions[1].format = swapchainObject.swapchainFormat;
attachmentDescriptions[1].samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
attachmentDescriptions[1].loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
attachmentDescriptions[1].storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
attachmentDescriptions[1].stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
attachmentDescriptions[1].stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
attachmentDescriptions[1].initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
attachmentDescriptions[1].finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR;

VkAttachmentReference offScreenColorWriteAttachmentReferance{};
offScreenColorWriteAttachmentReferance.attachment = 0U;
offScreenColorWriteAttachmentReferance.layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

VkAttachmentReference offScreenColorReadAttachmentReferance{};
offScreenColorReadAttachmentReferance.attachment = 0U;
offScreenColorReadAttachmentReferance.layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;

VkAttachmentReference onScreenColorAttachmentReferance{};
onScreenColorAttachmentReferance.attachment = 1U;
onScreenColorAttachmentReferance.layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

VkSubpassDescription subpasses[2]{};
subpasses[0].pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;
subpasses[0].colorAttachmentCount = 1U;
subpasses[0].pColorAttachments = &offScreenColorWriteAttachmentReferance;

subpasses[1].pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;
subpasses[1].colorAttachmentCount = 1U;
subpasses[1].pColorAttachments = &onScreenColorAttachmentReferance;
subpasses[1].inputAttachmentCount = 1U;
subpasses[1].pInputAttachments = &offScreenColorReadAttachmentReferance;

VkSubpassDependency subpassDependencies[2]{};
subpassDependencies[0].srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
subpassDependencies[0].dstSubpass = 0U;
subpassDependencies[0].srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
subpassDependencies[0].srcAccessMask = 0U;
subpassDependencies[0].dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
subpassDependencies[0].dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;

subpassDependencies[1].srcSubpass = 0U;
subpassDependencies[1].dstSubpass = 1U;
subpassDependencies[1].srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
subpassDependencies[1].srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
subpassDependencies[1].dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT;
subpassDependencies[1].dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT;

In short, first subpass expects offScreen image asVK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL in the beginning, some transitions occur and at the end offScreen image is converted back to   VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL. The problem is that offScreen image have to be created as VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED because of spec;therefore, I need to use vkCmdPipelineBarrier for transition before rendering operations happen. What should barrier's dstAccessMask, dstStageMask be?
